# Align the checkbox to left of the label

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox with ripple effects. The below code displays the label text first and then the checkbox

I wanted to display the checkbox first and then the label text. The entire div expands and shrinks sometimes,

```css
<style>
@keyframes ripple {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }

    20% {
        transform: scale(25,25);
        opacity: 1
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(40,40)
    }
}

#onoff+label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px
}

#onoff {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px
}

#onoff+label::after {
    content: '';
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -40px;
    transform: translate(-20px,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: background-color 1s;
    background-position: -2px -1px;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.4)
}

#onoff:checked+label::after {
    border: 2px solid #0f9d58;
    background-color: rgba(15,157,88,.7);
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfgBwEQARzBMMQpAAAAN0lEQVQI12NgQAEHGBgYHzAwMAMxO5DN38AgIM/AYGHHwFBTw8Bg94OBQf4DUBgqzdwAVI5qAACbXgn3nmfmHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
}

#onoff:disabled+label::after {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    background-image: none
}

#onoff+label::before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 50%;
    right: -10px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    width: 1.8px;
    height: 1.8px
}

#onoff:focus+label::before {
    animation: ripple 1s ease-out
}
</style>
```

```html
<div align="left" class="onoffdiv">
<input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column"/>
<label for="onoff" style="margin-right: 30px;" class="lbl gray">Turn on/off</label>
<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do so by using following code

```
#onoff+label {
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

#onoff+label::after {
    left: -10px;
    right: auto;
}

#onoff+label::before {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
}
```

```css
<style>
@keyframes ripple {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }

    20% {
        transform: scale(25,25);
        opacity: 1
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(40,40)
    }
}

#onoff+label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px
}

#onoff {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px
}

#onoff+label::after {
    content: '';
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -40px;
    transform: translate(-20px,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: background-color 1s;
    background-position: -2px -1px;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.4)
}

#onoff:checked+label::after {
    border: 2px solid #0f9d58;
    background-color: rgba(15,157,88,.7);
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfgBwEQARzBMMQpAAAAN0lEQVQI12NgQAEHGBgYHzAwMAMxO5DN38AgIM/AYGHHwFBTw8Bg94OBQf4DUBgqzdwAVI5qAACbXgn3nmfmHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
}

#onoff:disabled+label::after {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    background-image: none
}

#onoff+label::before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 50%;
    right: -10px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    width: 1.8px;
    height: 1.8px
}

#onoff:focus+label::before {
    animation: ripple 1s ease-out
}


#onoff+label {
margin-left: 30px;
position: relative;
}

#onoff+label::after {
left: -10px;
right: auto;
}

#onoff+label::before {
left: 0;
right: auto;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div align="left" class="onoffdiv">
<input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column"/>
<label for="onoff" class="lbl gray">Turn on/off</label>
<br/>
</div>
```